# The meaning of 'due' in "A change in strategy was due."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Iwata thought that a change in strategy was **due**. (Englichcentral.com)

Is this 'due' used in a figurative way of the definition #1 of Collins dictionary? Or how should I think about this? Is it common to use 'due' in this way?

> [Difinitions of due at Collins Dictionary:](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/due)
>
> adj.
>
> 1. owed or owing as a debt, right, etc.; payable   ⇒ "the first payment
>      is due"
> 2. suitable; fitting; proper   ⇒ "with all due respect"
> 3. as much as is required; enough; adequate   ⇒ "due care, in due time"
> 4. expected or scheduled to arrive or be ready; timed for a certain
>      hour or date   ⇒ "the plane is due at 6:30 P.M."

OK. I've sought out and found the context to the sentence.
Here it is:

> Video Transcript
>
> Satoru Iwata is not an household name, but he should be.
>   Most people, however, would recognize his brain children,...
>   ...the Nintendo DS and the Wii.
>   These two game systems completely changed the world of gaming.
>   It's hard to imagine gaming without them,...
>   ...but amazingly, the DS and Wii almost didn't happen!
>   It is only thanks to the innovative ideas of Iwata that we have these systems today.
>   Satoru Iwata was made the CEO of Nintendo in 2002.
>   At that time, the video game market was suffering...
>   ...and Nintendo was having trouble with its sales.
>   **Iwata thought that a change in strategy was due.**
>   Previously, the strategy in the game industry was...
>   ...to keep making the same kinds of games and consoles,...
>   ...but just improve their power and complexity.

[EDIT]
**1. What should I do when something like this?**
I would have chosen Merk's comment if that one was written as an answer. I understand the 'due' saying "it's time". Sadly no dictionary definitions exactly say so. I hear people say "I'm over due" when they worked for so long and requiring holidays, for example. Just 'required' feels lucking sense of urgency, doesn't it? I see Mark's answer says almost the same but "it's time" is more summarizing, maybe not in a good style for a dictionary definition though **2. I don't know how to say it better…**

Comment: +1, excellent example of the right way to ask a question about the dictionary definition of a word.

Answer (score 1):

I think the meaning in your example is better explained with the definitions in Google, [due](https://www.google.com/search?q=due), adjective sense 1 (and click the down arrow):

> expected at or planned for at a certain time

or

> (of a person) having reached a point where the thing mentioned is required or owed.

More context would be needed to be more exact.

Answer (score 1):

It means that she has come to the point where she thinks a change in strategy needs to happen. If a pregnant woman is "due," it means she's about to have a baby. If a change in strategy is due, it means it needs to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I've read more different dictionaries and I think I found a good one that gives me the solution. It's at [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/due) but it's happened to be a version of Collins. It says:

> due (djuː)
>
> adj
>
> 1. (postpositive) immediately payable
> 2. (postpositive) owed as a debt, irrespective of any date for payment
> 3. requisite; fitting; proper
> 4. (prenominal) adequate or sufficient; enough
> 5. (postpositive) expected or appointed to be present or arrive: the train is now due.
> 6. due to attributable to or caused by

and I think the 'due' in my question is 'requisite' of #3, or can be also fitting or proper.

Comment: Interestingly I don't think any of these definitions is exactly correct.  'Due' here means 'somebody believes that something should happen at a specific time.'  In other words, "Itawa thought that it was time for a change in strategy."

Answer (score 0):

The use of "due" here means necessary or required.